# Get chatroom link

Tags: support, chat

I want to create new chatroom about my question and add link of this created chatroom to my question, to discussion about my question. How can I get chatroom link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what site you want this for, but you need [100 rep here on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat-rooms) for that privilege. Instructions are on the privilege page.

You'll probably get there very soon once this question gets an upvote.